# Running multiple Kubernetes clusters on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

We're currently running a Kubernetes 1.0 cluster on AWS in production, and we'd like to spin up a second cluster to test out 1.1. Based on the [AWS helper functions](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/util.sh#L91-L98), it looks like multiple clusters aren't supported, but I wanted to be sure. There's [a doc](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/multi-cluster.html) that describes running multiple clusters, but it's fairly brief.

In general, we'd like to have a second cluster continuously running for testing purposes. It seems like this would be a fairly common need.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to run a second cluster by setting `INSTANCE_PREFIX` before running `kube-up`.  That variable in turn sets `CLUSTER_ID` which should parameterize everything in the `cluster/aws/*` scripts.

Comment: also the master node ip is fixed, you need to set it in the environment variable as well. also  it's `KUBE_AWS_INSTANCE_PREFIX` you  need to set not `instance_prefix`